# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined - react js

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, redux

Please help me! I am stacked with this problem as I am undergoing this React + Django E-commerce project. This happens when I try bringing Redux to the Home Screen. The list of products in my store are unable to load and returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".

Below are my codes, please help me. Thanks.

**HOME SCREEN**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Product from "../components/Product";
import { listProducts } from "../actions/productActions";

function HomeScreen() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { error, loading, products } = productList;
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts());
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Latest Products</h1>
      <Row>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

**PRODUCT ACTIONS**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { 
    PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
    PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
    PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL
 } from '../constants/productConstants'

 export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try{
        dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST})

        

        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products/')

        dispatch({
            type:PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })
    }catch(error){
            dispatch({
                type:PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
                payload:error.response && error.response.data.message
                    ? error.response.data.message
                    : error.message,
            })
    }
 }
```

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU3BG.jpg)

Comment: The initial state of `products` needs to be `[]`. Alternatively, use conditional rendering: `{ products && products.map((product) => ( ...`

Comment: instead of  `{ error, loading, products } = productList`, try using directly  `productList.products`, or `productList.error`, etc

Comment: You didn't specify a default value for "product" when the app started it is undefined until "product_list_success" is dispatched. You can specify initial state on reducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in async functions when getting data from server you should use conditinal rendering.
in the react code try it :

befor:

```
{products.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} />
          </Col>
        ))}
```

after:

```
{products && products.map((product) => (
              <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Product product={product} />
              </Col>
            ))}
```

tell me if its worked.

Comment: I really appreciate this, itworked by doing away with the error message. Now, the products I am fetching are not being displayed on my home page, it rather displays a blank screen.I can see my header and footer components but I can't see the products component. What else should I do please?

Comment: try to add return in the map